# What will make an org eligible for Einstein Opportunity Scoring?

Tags: administration, einstein, system-admin

As per release note ([Focus on the Right Deals with Opportunity Scores](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_sales_features_core_oppty_sfx.htm)) they mentioned only if an org is eligible I will be able to use this free (now onwards) functionality.

My question is what my org need to have in order to be eligible for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eligibility requirements appear to be a "secret," or, at least, they're not publicly posting this information at this time. However, the PDF does state that you'll get an email if you are eligible, and if you're otherwise not sure, you can just open a case with Support, and they'll tell you if you're eligible. Your best bet is to simply open a case with Support.

Comment: Thank you, yeah i did :). Do you think this will eventually be roll out to every org? I understand this will be a guess, but will be interesting to hear your thoughts :)

Comment: @manza No idea. I'm honestly kind of surprised they even did this, as it's pretty rare for a paid feature to go "free."